# kubernetes find out which container crashes in a pod

Tags: kubernetes

I have a pod with multiple containers. Now it reports CrashLoopBackOff.
How can I find out which container crashes. It is possible that all containers crash. But I just want to make sure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can describe pod to see detail

```
kubectl describe pod POD_NAME
```

Answer (score 0):

```
kubectl get events
```

This command will help you to check all the events including crash